# Why does my code return -nan in visual studio, but not in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, visual-studio-2017

My Gauss Elimination code's results are -nan in visual studio, but not in Linux.

And the Linux results are awful because at func Gauss_Eli how many I increase the variable `k` at for blocks the func is working... doesn't occur segment error.

What is wrong with my code?

```
float ** Gauss_Eli(float ** matrix, int n) {

    // -----------------------------------------------------
    // |                                                   |
    // |    Eliminate elements  except (i, i) element      |
    // |                                                   |
    // -----------------------------------------------------

    // Eliminate elements at lower triangle part

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < n + 1; k++) {
                float e;
                e = matrix[i][k] * (matrix[j][i] / matrix[i][i]);
                matrix[j][k] -= e;
            }
        }
    }

    // Eliminate elements at upper triangle part

    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
            for (int k = 0; k < n + 1; k++) {
                float e;
                e = matrix[i][k] * (matrix[j][i] / matrix[i][i]);
                matrix[j][k] -= e;
            }
        }
    }

    // Make 1 elements i, i

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n + 1; j++) matrix[i][j] /= matrix[i][i];

    return matrix;
}

int main() {
    float ** matrix;
    int n;
    printf("Matrix Size : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    // Malloc variable matrix for Matrix

    matrix = (float**)malloc(sizeof(float) * n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) matrix[i] = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float) * (n + 1));

    printf("Input elements : \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n + 1; j++) scanf("%f", &matrix[i][j]);

    matrix = Gauss_Eli(matrix, n);
    printf("Output result : \n");

    //Print matrix after elimination

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n + 1; j++) printf("%.6f ", matrix[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a division by zero somewhere. Check all of the divisions you have.

Comment: Sure `matrix[i][i]` is never 0.0 before use in `.../ matrix[i][i]);`?

Comment: `matrix = (float**)malloc(sizeof(float) * n);` is wrong.  Use `matrix = malloc(sizeof *matrix * n);` and avoid the error of using the wrong size.

Comment: @chux That was a good spot :)

Comment: Aside: Consider `int j = 0; j <= n; j++` rather that `int j = 0; j < n + 1; j++`.  ( a style issue)

Answer (score 0):

1.) OP allocates memory using the wrong type.  This may lead to issues of insufficient memory and all sorts of UB and explain the difference between systems as they could have differing pointer and `float` sizes.

```
float ** matrix;                      
//                                  v--- wrong type    
// matrix = (float**)malloc(sizeof(float) * n);
```

Instead allocate to the size of the referenced variable.  Easier to code (and get right), review and maintain.

```
matrix = malloc(sizeof *matrix * n);
if (matrix == NULL) Handle_Error();
```

2.) Code should look for division by 0.0

```
        //for (int k = 0; k < n + 1; k++) {
        //    float e;
        //    e = matrix[i][k] * (matrix[j][i] / matrix[i][i]);
        //    matrix[j][k] -= e;
        //}
        if (matrix[i][i] == 0.0) Handle_Error();
        float m = matrix[j][i] / matrix[i][i];
        for (int k = 0; k < n + 1; k++) {
            matrix[j][k] -= matrix[i][k]*m;
        }
```

3.) General problem solving tips:

Check return values of `scanf("%f", &matrix[i][j]);`.  It is 1?

Enable all warnings.

Especially for debug, print FP using `"%e"` rather than `"%f"`.

4.) Numerical analysis tip:  Insure exact subtraction when `i==j`

```
        if (i == j) {
          for (int k = 0; k < n + 1; k++) {
            matrix[j][k] = 0.0;
          }
        else {
          if (matrix[i][i] == 0.0) Handle_Divide_by_0();
          float m = matrix[j][i] / matrix[i][i];
          for (int k = 0; k < n + 1; k++) {
            matrix[j][k] -= matrix[i][k]*m;
          }
        }
```